# Use jQuery to show/toggle each element only showing one on screen at any particular moment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some links:

1. About
2. Portfolio
3. Resume

When I click 'About', I want the About element to show, but the Portfolio and Resume elements to be hidden (and so on through the pattern)...

My code is structured like this (clipped to the parts that are needed):

HTML:

```
<section id="attCatch">
    <div class="container_12">
        <h1 class="attCatchText">The name's Jake. I like to make things.</h1>
        <nav id="topMainNav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" title="#" class="aboutLink">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="#" class="portfolioLink">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="#" class="resumeLink">Resume</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</section>
<section id="contentLoader">
    <div class="container_12">
    <section class="mn_pages">
        <article class="about_page">
            <h1>About stuff</h1>
        </article>

        <article class="portfolio_page">
            <h1>Portfolio stuff</h1>
        </article>

        <article class="resume_page">
            <h1>Resume stuff</h1>
        </article>
    </section>
    </div>
</section>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.mn_pages').hide();
     var i = 0;
     $('.topMainNav').each(function(){
         $(this).click(function(){ 
             $('.mn_pages:eq('+$(this).data('idf')+')').toggle('slow');
         });
         $(this).data('idf',i);
         i++;
    });
});
```

I thought my jQuery code would work, but this is the not the case.

Included JS fiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/MsYdJ/

Comment: can you please creatd fiddle with all css so that we can check ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MsYdJ/  ---  Thanks for the fast reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this way:

#### [FIDDLE FOR TRYOUT](http://jsfiddle.net/MsYdJ/12/)

```
$(function(){
   $('.mn_pages').find('article').hide(); // <---HIDES ON PAGE LOAD
   $('#topMainNav a').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var page = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
      $('.mn_pages').find('article').hide(); // <---OPENED ONE HIDES
      $('[class="'+page+'_page"]').show(); //<------CLICKED ONE SHOWS
   });
});
```

Comment: I didn't do that, but thank you so much! You are a God of Men.

Comment: "God of Men" Oh NO Plz! Thanks anyway but i am just another friend of yours.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following selector to hide the `articles` on page load:

```
$('.mn_pages > article').hide();
```

Then the following to show/hide the correct element:

```
$('#topMainNav li').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.mn_pages > article').hide().eq($(this).index()).show();
});
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GhwYb/)

Comment: Thanks! I will remember this for future cases, and would have used this if Jai's had not worked so well. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. The only thing I guess I should have mentioned with this is that it relies on the indexes of the navigation elements and the articles to be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

This is an implementation wherein you require the class/Id names to be constant, wand changing the name of the links any other time-[This is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MsYdJ/16/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#contentLoader .mn_pages').children().hide();
        $('#topMainNav li').each(function () {
            var targetClass=($(this).children().attr("class")).replace("Link","_page");
            $(this).bind("click",function(){
                $("#contentLoader .mn_pages").children().hide();
                $("#contentLoader .mn_pages ."+targetClass).show();
            });
        });
});
```